# How do I get two different audio streams simutaneaously in my computer

Tags: windows, audio, vlc-media-player, headphones

I want to watch two movies simultaneously.

Video is not a problem since I can run 2 instances of vlc.

Issue is audio.

How can I configure vlc ( or some other software ) so that I get audio from one movie on my left earphone and the other on my right.

How can I achieve this

Comment: Open two instances of VLC - set the balance of one to all left and the other to all right? Impressive talent by the way...!

Comment: @Jonno thanks for the tip but I'm afraid VLC has this functionality. Any other media player that you might know of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use VLC, but MPC-HC definitely has this functionality.

- Right click the video
- Audio Track -> Options
- Click 'Enable custom channel mapping'
- Select either Front Left or Front Right

Open another MPC-HC and do the same, but for the other option.

[image]